# Object spread parameter for this

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6, this

I am using dependency injection in Angular controller class (ES6)

```
class Ctrl{
  constructor($scope, service1, service2){
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.service1= service1;
    this.service2= service2;
  }
}
```

What if i have 15 dependencies, How can i write this more elegantly in ES6/7 using spread operator or something?

Comment: You could use typescript instead: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the recipe looks like

```
static get $inject() {
  return ['$scope', ...];
}

constructor(...deps)
  this.constructor.$inject.forEach((depName, i) => {
    this[depName] = deps[i];
  });
  ...
```

Comment: will this preserve all the other deeply nested keys inside 'this', in other words will it reserve 'this', only decorating it rather than modifying it?

Comment: and any babel settings to be followed?

Comment: No, it's pure ES6. This will add `$scope`, etc keys to `this`. If the properties with the same name exist on the prototype, they will be replaced. Nothing that you wouldn't expect from doing `this.$scope  = ...` manually.